# Pulling in a second value for a Cross Tab with MySQL

Tags: mysql, conditional-operator

I have the following query ...

```
SELECT COUNT(Department) as DeptCount, Survey.Department, Department.DepartmentName 
FROM Survey JOIN Department ON Survey.Department = Department.DeptID 
Where SurveyCompleted is not null GROUP BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY Department;
```

The only problem is the field "Department" that I do the count on doesn't always have a value entered (for a variety of reasons).  There is another field Employee.DepartmentId that I could use, but I'm not sure how to create the same effect if I use an inline IF or similar construct.

Essentially what I would like to see as output is:

```
DeptCount    Department    DepartmentName
43           2             Department1
68           9             Department2
83           13            Department3
```

Right now I get an additional row as the first result

```
DeptCount    Department    DepartmentName
93           0             <blank>
43           2             Department1
68           9             Department2
83           13            Department3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does a Department of 0 actually exist? What would be in `Survey.Department` and `Department.DeptID` in cases where no Department value is entered? Is it just a null value?

Comment: If they don't fill in the result for Survey.Department it would get a value of 0 which is invalid.  Employee.DepartmentId should be used in that case and would contain a presumed correct department code (non-zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was trying to make it overly complicated.

All I needed to do was name the result that was created from a conditional operator. Then I can group by that value ... and it works (or seems to).

Here is my resultant query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Department) as DeptCount, 
  IF(Survey.Department=0, Employee.DepartmentId, Survey.Department) As MyDept, 
  Department.DepartmentName 
FROM Survey JOIN Department ON Survey.Department = Department.DeptID
  JOIN Employee ON EmployeeId = Employee.Id
WHERE SurveyCompleted is not null
GROUP BY MyDept;
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try this? By making the join a left join, we get all of the records from `Survey` and any matching records from `Department`. Then we can aggregate them.

```
SELECT COUNT(Department) as DeptCount, coalesce(Survey.Department, 0)
, Department.DepartmentName 
FROM Survey 
left JOIN Department ON Survey.Department = Department.DeptID
Where SurveyCompleted is not null 
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY Department;
```

By the way, `group by` automatically orders, so if you are grouping you don't need the `order by`.

Comment: But the coalesce(Survey.Department, 0) doesn't eliminate the problem of getting 0 values when Department isn't filled in ... that essentially is my issue.  I want to pull from Employee.DeptartmentId if Survey.Department is 0 or blank and use that in my count/grouping.

Comment: I tried your answer ... and got the exact same results as my original ... so it didn't seem to resolve the problem (getting rid of the first row with a 0 for the DepartmentID code)

Comment: What do you get if you just run `select * FROM Survey 
LEFT JOIN Department ON Survey.Department = Department.DeptID`?

Comment: I get one (pseudo-random) record for each department ... 34 records.  I have 1443 records in Survey and 32 in Department ... I get a record with a null record for the Department and I'll have to see what the other record is (that isn't inherently in the Department table).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(Department) as DeptCount, Survey.Department, Department.DepartmentName 
FROM Survey JOIN Department ON Survey.Department = Department.DeptID 
Where SurveyCompleted is not null and Survey.Department is not null and Survey.Department <> ''   
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT   
ORDER BY Department;
```

Comment: That eliminated the 0 values ... so it's half way to where I want to go ... but it just left out the 0 values rather than assigning them to the departments the employee had in their original table (Employee.DepartmentId) ... which I would like to use *if* they don't fill in (Survey.Department).

Comment: I know I'll need to add another join to bring in the Employee.DepartmentID values ... I'm thinking if I can create a table in memory then I can assign the Department value dynamically with IF(Survey.Department > 0, Survey.Department, Employee.DepartmentId) ... I just don't know how to do that kind of inline if when I'm grouping and counting based on the resulting value.